# How can I trigger api from node js in response to apiai query request?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, api-ai

I am using apiai module in node js and I am calling apiai query. I want to call my webservice from my nodejs not apiai webhook. Is there any mechanism.

Comment: Is it a SOAP webservice?

Comment: No its rest with nodejs.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What is not working currently, what is the desired outcome, can you share some code?

Comment: Why don't you do a webhook to api ai and then make the handler call your REST api. You can add a switch case in order to call different REST endpoints pending in the api ai action. Of course this is a fairly simple setup and if you elaborate I can give you better advice on the node architecture